# Find in XML through vba

Tags: xml, vba

I have a **xml** file like below.

```
  <ConnectedAP apName="I16:ETH0" iedName="IE16">    
    <Address>   
      <P type="OSI-AP-Title">1,3,9999,23</P>    
      <P type="IP">172.18.12.243</P>    
      <P type="OSI-AE-Qualifier">23</P> 
      <P type="OSI-PSEL">0001</P>   
      <P type="OSI-SSEL">0001</P>   
      <P type="OSI-TSEL">00000001</P>   
    </Address>  
  </ConnectedAP>    
  <ConnectedAP apName="S1" iedName="STGK16999997422">   
    <Address>   
      <P type="OSI-AP-Title">1,3,9999,23</P>    
      <P type="IP">172.18.12.24</P> 
      <P type="OSI-AE-Qualifier">23</P> 
      <P type="OSI-PSEL">00000001</P>   
      <P type="OSI-SSEL">0001</P>   
      <P type="OSI-TSEL">0001</P>   
    </Address>  
  </ConnectedAP>    
  <ConnectedAP apName="LD0" iedName="GTG699999731RET">  
    <Address>
```

I need to find the value of `iedName` via **vba**.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome to SO, I could not find a clear question, can you modify your post and define a question to solve? Please read> [How to Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a quick function that loops through each //ConnectedAP that outputs the @iedName attribute.

```
Public Sub getXML()
  Set XML = CreateObject("MSXML2.DOMDocument")
  Dim strXML As String
  strXML = "<xml><ConnectedAP apName='I16:ETH0' iedName='IE16'>    <Address>      <P type='OSI-AP-Title'>1,3,9999,23</P>      <P type='IP'>172.18.12.243</P>      <P type='OSI-AE-Qualifier'>23</P>      <P type='OSI-PSEL'>0001</P>      <P type='OSI-SSEL'>0001</P>      <P type='OSI-TSEL'>00000001</P>    </Address>  </ConnectedAP>  <ConnectedAP apName='S1' iedName='STGK16999997422'>   <Address>      <P type='OSI-AP-Title'>1,3,9999,23</P>      <P type='IP'>172.18.12.24</P>      <P type='OSI-AE-Qualifier'>23</P>      <P type='OSI-PSEL'>00000001</P>      <P type='OSI-SSEL'>0001</P>      <P type='OSI-TSEL'>0001</P>    </Address></ConnectedAP></xml>"
  Call XML.LoadXML(strXML)
  Dim ndXML As Object
  Set ndXML = XML.SelectNodes("//ConnectedAP")
  For i = 0 To ndXML.Length - 1
    MsgBox ndXML(i).getAttribute("iedName")
  Next i

End Sub
```

Comment: It's an awesome solution @William Walseth. +1 for this. What if I've a text file in my desktop loaded with the same content you defined in your `strXML` and I would like to use the way you did here then how would the change will look like? I tried with `strXML = ThisWorkbook.Path & "\ht_ml.txt"` but it doesn't seem to work at all. Should I bring about any changes other than what you have done up there? Thanks.

Comment: Use the XML.Load( strFullPathToYourFile) to load the XML

Comment: This is working for me. Thanks... But how i will read the IP address <P type="IP">172.18.12.243</P>  , because, here i cannot give a particular attribute. I need to extract IP address as will.  I am new to the coding .

Comment: ndXML(i).SelectSingleNode( "//p[@type='IP']").InnerText